# Finding locked files in svn without checking out

Tags: svn

How can I find the files that I have locked in a svn tree that is so large (tens of thousands of files) that I want to avoid checking everything out:
Can I do some `svn <magic arguments> | grep <MyUserName>` to find files locked by me ?

Alternative question: Can I remove all my locks (unlock all files) in a svn tree at once ?

`svn status` works only after checking everything out and
`svnadmin lslocks` is only useful on the server, which I don't have access to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While rrirower is technically correct about `svnadmin lslocks`, you can think about possible alternative ways

1. One-time action "Get FULL WC" (can be obtained on server's local FS, i.e. relatively fast, and moved as tree of files to final destination) will get you `svn st -u` (all locked in repo files)
2. `svn ls -R -v /REPO/ROOT`

> With --verbose, the following fields will be shown for each item:
>
> ```
> Revision number of the last commit
> Author of the last commit
> If locked, the letter 'O'.  (Use 'svn info URL' to see details)
> Size (in bytes)
> Date and time of the last commit
> ```

With both methods you'll get only *indication* of locking (locked file name), which sign you'll have to expand with `svn info URL/TO/LOCKED/FILE` and extract `Lock Owner: XXX` string from output (maybe use XML-output of command and XML-aware tools)

### Answer on alternative question

Yes, you can (to some degree)

**Before unlocking**

Prepare WC with [Sparse Directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) (with only dirs, which have files with your locks)

**Unlocking**

Modify single locked file in WC and commit the whole WC. According to [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.locking.html)

> After the commit completes successfully, all of the repository locks
>   that were mentioned are released—even on files that weren't committed.
>   This is meant to discourage users from being sloppy about locking or
>   from holding locks for too long. If Harry haphazardly locks 30 files
>   in a directory named images because he's unsure of which files he
>   needs to change, yet changes only four of those files, when he runs
>   svn commit images, the process will still release all 30 locks.

I expect all files will be unlocked

Another way of unlocking is using `svn unlock --target ARG`, there ARG holds all URLs of your locks (URL per line), will work even without WC

Comment: What I finally did to unlock all the files locked by me without checking everything out was `svn ls -Rv $Repos |
sed -nr "s\\^ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +O +[0-9]+ ... [0-3][0-9] +[^ ]+ \\$Repos/\\p" |
xargs svn info |
gawk -vIGNORECASE=1 '$1=="URL:" { URL=$2 } $1=="Lock" && $2=="Owner:" && $3~'/$USERNAME/' { print URL }' |
xargs svn unlock` It took half an hour to execute - not sure how long a full checkout of 50 k files would have taken. The Sparse Directories method misses a `--depth directories` option so was not useful for me. Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get a list of locked files by using:
[svnadmin lslocks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.lslocks.html)

And, I think that:
[svn cleanup](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.cleanup.html) will remove your locks.

Comment: cleanup 1) work with **WC only** 2) unlock not "locked files" in terms of SVN, but locked WC after badly terminated operations with it: see  "`The Three Meanings of “Lock”` on http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.locking.html

Comment: `svnadmin lslocks` appears to work on the server only, which I don't have access to.And as @LazyBadger already mentioned, `svn cleanup`  works on a different type of locks being irrelevant here.

Comment: @Juergen - you can at least try `svnrdump dump` (only `HEAD`) and load dump locally  (with `--incremental` dumps of range later) and check how lock-state transferred over dumping (you can dump-load even single locked file with svnrdump)

Comment: @LazyBadger Loading a dump locally seems roughly equivalent to checking everything (in my case, 50 k files) out, which is what i not wanted to do.